# Position loader while the image is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load

UPDATED LINKS

I'm trying to add a loading image on my images while they are loaded, but I don't know why it doesn't want to work for me...

I'm trying the solution's posted here: [Loaders java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956047/jquery-loading-image-while-elements-loads)

I want to add a loading images on the `.thumb` images while they are loading. Because I'm copying this element when it is loaded and doen't look good while the images are beeing loaded.

I'm not very strong at scripting, so please forgive me...

[Here is where I want to place it](http://www.turdidesigns.com/bin/dumies/galleriffic/add_images.html)

Thank you,

UPDATE: In case you have a good internet connection, here is a screenshot of what is happening and what I want to hide, while the images are being loaded.

[image]

Comment: vague question will get vague answer.what is currently happening ? where is the css and jquery code?

Comment: the jquery code is in Listing.js, the css is visible with google chrome. I don't understand the question...... when you click on the listing design (grey) you should see as in the image http://i.imgur.com/waat6ZH.jpg

Comment: i believe ebay is not maintained by you !!

Comment: ebay not, but the script's and custom css are !!!

Comment: the question isn't in maintaining or something, it's a scripting question, only it functions inside of ebay.

Comment: I hope after the updates, it will be easier to understand what I want. Thanks.